# Writing express app but order of routes is affecting the app and throwing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
app.get('/campgrounds/:id/edit', async (req,res) =>{
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('campgrounds/edit', { campground });
})
app.get('/campgrounds/:id', async (req,res) =>{
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground });
})
```

The above codde is working but for :
If I am writing `app.get('/campgrounds/:id/edit', async (req,res)` after `app.get('/campgrounds/:id', async (req,res)`
my code does not work
why is that? Can someone give detailed explanation how routing works in express apps?

Comment: Express does not attempt to match ALL urls you give it. Instead Express tries one URL at a time in the order you have defined. Since the url `/campgrounds/1234/edit` matches the pattern `/campgrounds/:id` it will trigger that handler. The order matters because Express only checks the URLs you define one at a time in the order you defined them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes order do matter while working with routes in general.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes):

> Note: The URL /book/create will be matched by a route like /book/:bookId (which will extract a "bookId" value of 'create'). The first route that matches an incoming URL will be used, so if you want to process /book/create URLs separately, their route handler must be defined before your /book/:bookId route.